# Jquery Ajax Call performance tuning

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

[image]I have observed certain functionality. In my MVC web application ,from view file i am calling three ajax calls .
Inside the success event of first ajax call i am calling second and inside the success event of second ajax function i am calling the third.

When I observed the elapsed time taken by the each ajax call in the network section of firebug .I have noticed that the third ajax call got 1.5 to 2.5 seconds elapsed time. but when i move the third ajax call as the first one then the time taken would be 450 Millisecond to 600 Milliseconds.

I am not able to understand why the elapsed time taken varies when we call the ajax inside success event of other and calling individually.

Can any one explain me why this variation occurs?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show some code so that we are able to better visualize what you did before and then what you did after?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really do this in a comment so this will be deleted shortly:

In **Google Chrome** you can see a breakdown of the network call:

[image]

**FireBug** does this too:

[image]

Can you identify which part is lagging?

**Update:**

Your AJAX calls are executing at the exact **SAME** time so the first call is holding up the second call:

[image]

Comment: **`Waiting`** is the time it takes for your server-side script to execute.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I know Waiting is the time taken from the server.I am getting the waiting time as high. But my concern when i move the ajax calls individually the time taken gets varies. I have updated my question with screen shot please refer.

Comment: Hi, you have only shown the overall time. Please hover your mouse over the yellow bar to see the breakdown of events and update your post. Do you see the the stuff I highlighted in red? Please show that piece

Comment: Again thanks for your reply. I have updated the screen shot with the waiting time. My question is when I call a Third ajax call(calling each ajax call separately without calling inside another ajax's success function) separately it is giving some shorter response time but, when i call the third ajax call inside the success event of second ajax call it is taking more time.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Your screenshot confirms that AJAX is definitely **not** the issue so now we can move on. ***Most likely***, the issue is due to something called a session lock. Your ASP script of `ReviseProposal?SalesModeID=3` is probably opening the session and closing it at the very end of execution. Because AJAX is asynchronous it is able to send a request to `BindDeviceForContractTerm` before `RevisedProposal` has finished. So to avoid messing up the session data, ASP is forcing `BindDeviceForContractTerm` to wait for the session to become available.

Comment: Thanks for your instant reply. I am using session variables inside the ReviseProposal?SalesModeID=3 call. There is nothing like Locking the session inside this.Can you assist me to find if anything  locking because i could not find which is blocking the call. But when i call individual Ajax calls response time gets better.

Comment: I do not program in ASP but in PHP my debugging/benchmarking approach would be to add `$start = microtime(true);` at the beginning of the script and then `echo '<hr><br>function x(): '.(microtime(true) - $start).' seconds<br><hr>';` at various points until I can pinpoint the problem area. There are various benchmarking and profiling plugins/methods available, like **[XDEBUG for PHP](http://xdebug.org/)**, so you need to find out what is available for ASP. Maybe your MVC framework has something built-in? CodeIgniter for PHP has a ` class profiler` which I can invoke.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion .I will track the issue.

Comment: No problem, if you have any further confusion about AJAX then let me know

Comment: Hi, I have one more doubt. When I use async: false instead of true in the Ajax call then the elapsed response time gets better. Let me know your comment on this.

Comment: Please see my **`Update:`**, ASP is causing the slowdown. Profile your script(s) to find out why.